# Character animation. Linking child and parent layers in After Effects using Duik 16

Tags: after-effects, animation

I am currently attempting to animate a character using Duik 16 but I am having trouble linking some of the body parts so they stay connected.

I imported an illustrator layered file into After Effects and was methodical in my approach creating layers for the body parts of the character.

To illustrate further, I used the puppet warp tool at 3 separate positions on the leg, then I created the bones from those pins using the DUIK 16 rigging plugin. From those bones I was then able to create a controller using the auto rig button to allow the body part to bend about. The eventual goal is to be able to create a walking cycle.

I followed suit with this method using the tutorial in the [video link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxGmEAC4Rsw) as a basis. I would like the rear foot (in its own layer) to move as a child of the rear leg layer. For example when the leg moves upwards the rear foot should stay connected. I understand you can use the auto rig feature on the entire body if the parts are carefully named, however I wish to just warp the leg with the controller to get the same effect. I have uploaded an attached image to illustrate the problem. There is a parent constraint button which looks like it was designed for this sort of issue but I am having difficulty finding any documentation on how to use it online. I tried parenting the rear leg and rear foot layer but to no avail.
[image: Foot and leg disconnect]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to know exactly without having the project to look at. What happens if you parent the foot to the controller, so that movement and rotation applied to the controller is applied to the foot?

Comment: Try parenting the foot-graphic-layer / it's parent to the ankle-controller.